# How to convert large text matrix to sparse format

Tags: python, memory, sparse-matrix

I have 1million * 4096 matrix as a text file. I want to transfer it to sparse matrix format for saving memory and do some computation. I have written following code, but it is killed because of memory issue. My computer have 32GB memory and 8GB swap. It is still not enough. Could someone give some advices for modification. Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from datetime import datetime as time
from scipy import sparse, io
from numpy import array
import os, sys, getopt

def process(input_file_name):
    crt_row_no = 0 # Current row number
    crt_col_no = 0 # Current column number
    row = []
    col = []
    data = []
    count = 0
    line = 0
    with open(input_file_name) as infile:
        for crt_line in infile:  
            value = crt_line.split(' ')
            for v in value:
                float_v = float(v)
                #print float_v
                if float_v != 0:
                    row.append(crt_row_no)
                    col.append(crt_col_no)
                    data.append(float_v)
                    count += 1
                    if count%1000 == 0:
                        print count, line 
                crt_col_no +=1
            crt_row_no += 1
            crt_col_no = 0
            line += 1
    return sparse.coo_matrix((data,(row,col))).tocsr()

def main(argv):
    inputfile = ''
    outputfile = ''

    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:",["ifile=","ofile="])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print 'python <script name> -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
        sys.exit(2)

    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-h':
            print 'python <script name> -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-i"):
            inputfile = arg
        elif opt in ("-o"):
            outputfile = arg

    print 'Reading images from "', inputfile
    print 'Writing vectors to "', outputfile

    input_file_name = inputfile

    """ ################### START PROGRAM ############################ """  

    print "--------------STRAT-----------------"
    running_time = time.now()
    data_matrix = process(input_file_name)
    print "Total time:" + str(time.now() - running_time)
    print "Writing to file."
    io.mmwrite(outputfile, data_matrix)

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: What proportion of your values is zero? How much memory is the process using?

Comment: Do you mean you have 1million  text files, each file is 4K?

Comment: @ccf I am not, I have a matrix (1m * 4029) saved in a txt file.

Comment: How large is the txt file? What I can think of, is that If it is too large, you could read/write the file in chunks.

Comment: @ccf I have tried that. Thanks.